# Kivy: Delete Data in JSON using RecycleView

Tags: python, json, kivy

I want to delete data from a JSON file using `store.delete('key_of_dictionary')` by selecting a label in RecycleView, then pressing a 'Delete' button.

I've made my code to select the labels, and get the value, but I cannot pass it to a method/function. The method must be in `class SelectableLabel(...)`, as it seems. I'm not sure how to access that class.

I would appreciate any insight. **Thank you in advance!**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from operator import itemgetter
import json

kv_string = """
ScreenManager:
    id: manager

    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .2,.2,.5,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y: .3
                cols:4
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Rank'
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Ratings'
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Name'
                    size_hint_x: 2
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Score'
                    on_press:
                        #arrange the boxing in ascending or descending order

            RecycleView:
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in app.new_new_sorted_data]
                viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'

                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 4
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True

            Button:
                size_hint_y: .3
                text: 'Press to Use Method'
                on_press:
                    SelectableLabel().function()

<SelectableLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<MyButton@Button>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,1
"""
class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):

    def function(self):
        print('Take the value in rv.data[index] if 4 % == 0 then do\nstore.delete(rv.data[index])')

    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_layout(self, rv, index, layout, viewport):
        mod = index % 4
        size_hints = [(0.5, None), (1, None), (2, None), (1, None)]
        layout['size_hint'] = size_hints[mod]
        colors = (1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,1), (0,1,1,1)
        layout['color'] = colors[mod]
        super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_layout(rv, index, layout, viewport)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True

        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)
            if self.index % 4 == 0:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 3)
                return
            elif self.index % 4 == 1:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 1)
                return
            elif self.index % 4 == 2:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 1)
                return
            elif self.index % 4 == 3:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 3)
                return

    index_list = []

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        self.selected = is_selected

        if is_selected:
            self.index_list.append(rv.data[index]) if index % 4 == 0 else self.index_list
            print(self.index_list)  if index % 4 == 0 else ''
            #print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            try:
                self.index_list.remove(rv.data[index]) if index % 4 == 0 else self.index_list
                print(self.index_list) if index % 4 == 0 else ''
                #print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            except:
                pass

class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleGridLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    store = JsonStore('file.json')
    store.put('Example: 1', value_1 = 'Rating: C', value_2 = 10, value_3 = 'Zack')
    store.put('Example: 2', value_1 = 'Rating: C', value_2 = 13, value_3 = 'Kate')
    store.put('Example: 3', value_1 = 'Rating: A', value_2 = 32, value_3 = 'Pete')
    store.put('Example: 4', value_1 = 'Rating: B', value_2 = 24, value_3 = 'Toby')
    store.put('Example: 5', value_1 = 'Rating: D', value_2 = 03, value_3 = 'Lars')

# ---------------------- v Sorting Data v ----------------------

    json_data = open('./file.json')
    score_data = json.load(json_data)

    newlist = []
    newnewlist = []

    for x in score_data:
        newlist.append(x)

    for y in newlist:
        newnewlist.append(score_data[str(y)])

    print(newlist)
    print(newnewlist)

    sorted_data = sorted(newnewlist,key=itemgetter('value_2'), reverse = True)
    new_sorted_data = []

    for z in sorted_data:
        new_sorted_data.append(z.values())

    new_new_sorted_data = []

    for x,y,z in new_sorted_data:

        new_new_sorted_data.append(newlist.pop())
        new_new_sorted_data.append(x)
        new_new_sorted_data.append(y)
        new_new_sorted_data.append(z)

# ---------------------- ^ Sorting Data ^ ----------------------

    def build(self):
        root_widget = Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Do you want to select n items and after pressing the button should you delete those items?

Comment: Hey @eyllanesc , yes, I want to **first** select them **then if** I press the bottom button, they will be deleted. It seems like the method/function will have to be in `class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):` but I'm not sure how to access it, nor how to pass the `index_list` that is filled with the keys.

Comment: that you must explain in your question, so I recommend you edit your question and add that information.

Comment: Okay, I edited the description to make it clear.
 **Thank you for letting me know!!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got my sample code to do what I wanted. I went through the `MyApp` class to get to the `SelectLabel` class. I also found a way to delete specific JSON keys through `RecycleView`. I didn't comment this piece of code because it's just a sample, but if someone is using this as a reference and needs assistance, feel free to message me.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from operator import itemgetter
import json

kv_string = """
ScreenManager:
    id: manager

    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .2,.2,.5,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y: .3
                cols:4
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Rank'
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Ratings'
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Name'
                    size_hint_x: 2
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Score'
                    on_press:
                        #arrange the boxing in ascending or descending order

            RecycleView:
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in app.new_new_sorted_data]
                viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'

                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 4
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True

            Button:
                size_hint_y: .3
                text: 'Press to Use Method'
                on_press:
                    app.pre_function()

<SelectableLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<MyButton@Button>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,1
"""
class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):

    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_layout(self, rv, index, layout, viewport):
        mod = index % 4
        size_hints = [(0.5, None), (1, None), (2, None), (1, None)]
        layout['size_hint'] = size_hints[mod]
        colors = (1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,1), (0,1,1,1)
        layout['color'] = colors[mod]
        super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_layout(rv, index, layout, viewport)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True

        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)
            if self.index % 4 == 0:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 3)
                return
            elif self.index % 4 == 1:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index -1)
                return
            elif self.index % 4 == 2:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index -1)
                return
            elif self.index % 4 == 3:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 3)
                return

    index_list = []

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        self.selected = is_selected

        if is_selected:
            self.index_list.append(rv.data[index]) if index % 4 == 0 else self.index_list
            #print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            try:
                self.index_list.remove(rv.data[index]) if index % 4 == 0 else self.index_list
                #print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            except:
                pass

class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleGridLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    store = JsonStore('file.json')
    store.put('Example: 1', value_1 = 'Rating: C', value_2 = 10, value_3 = 'Zack')
    store.put('Example: 2', value_1 = 'Rating: C', value_2 = 13, value_3 = 'Kate')
    store.put('Example: 3', value_1 = 'Rating: A', value_2 = 32, value_3 = 'Pete')
    store.put('Example: 4', value_1 = 'Rating: B', value_2 = 24, value_3 = 'Toby')
    store.put('Example: 5', value_1 = 'Rating: D', value_2 = 03, value_3 = 'Lars')

# ---------------------- v Sorting Data v ----------------------

    new_new_sorted_data = ListProperty([])

    def sort_data(self):
        try:
            self.store = JsonStore('file.json')
            self.new_new_sorted_data = []
            json_data = open('./file.json')
            score_data = json.load(json_data)

            newlist = []
            newnewlist = []

            for x in score_data:
                newlist.append(x)

            for y in newlist:
                newnewlist.append(score_data[str(y)])

            print(newlist)
            print(newnewlist)

            sorted_data = sorted(newnewlist,key=itemgetter('value_2'), reverse = True)
            new_sorted_data = []

            for z in sorted_data:
                new_sorted_data.append(z.values())


            for x,y,z in new_sorted_data:

                self.new_new_sorted_data.append(newlist.pop())
                self.new_new_sorted_data.append(x)
                self.new_new_sorted_data.append(y)
                self.new_new_sorted_data.append(z)
        except:
            pass
# ---------------------- ^ Sorting Data ^ ----------------------

# --------------------- v Deleting Data v ----------------------

    only_key_values_list = []
    only_key_values = []

    def pre_function(self):
        self.only_key_values_list = []
        self.only_key_values = []

        for value in SelectableLabel().index_list:
            self.only_key_values_list.append(value.values())
            for keys in self.only_key_values_list:
                for key in keys:
                    try:
                        self.store.delete(str(key))
                    except:
                        pass
            self.sort_data()


# --------------------- ^ Deleting Data ^ ----------------------
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sort_data()

    def build(self):
        root_widget = Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```